# Microsoft Azure Docker Compose with multiplay images

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose

Need some help with Microsoft Azure and Docker.
I am using App Service > Docker Compose (preview) and trying to create the right docker compose file on their platform for my 2 images can run in one docker compose. Backend is written in Django and Frontend is created in React

```
version: '3.7'
services:
   backend:
     image: myrepo.azurecr.io/back:backend_v1
     environment:
       - WEBSITES_PORT=8000
   front:
     image: myrepo.azurecr.io/front:v1
     links:
       - backend
     environment:
       WEBSITES_PORT=3000
```

This is look of my docker-compose, after I run it on azure my website is working but only backend. When i run it locally under localhost:3000 there is my frontend and under localhost:8000 there is my backend
But i cannot make it work this way on azure. I mean ideally it would be awesome to have access under mywebsite.../frond and mywebsite.../back but i will take any solution you can provide to how modify my files to make it work?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Or what's more do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements, I think you have a misunderstanding of the Azure Web App. The Azure Web App only can expose one port to the outside. It means if you want to expose the front to the outside to be accessible, then the backend is inaccessible. The opposite is also it.

And you should not add the environment variable `WEBSITES_PORT` inside the docker-compose file, what you need to do is add this environment variable for the Web App in the portal:

[image]

or using the CLI command like this:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group myResourceGroup --name <app-name> --settings WEBSITES_PORT=port
```

So the solution for you is that choose one image you want to expose to be accessible and set the environment variable `WEBSITES_PORT` for it.

Comment: @NiewaszBiznes If you have any other problems with this case, please let me know. I'm glad to help you. And if it solves your problem, please accept it as the answer :-)

Comment: Ok man, i got a little different question, i am running above application on VM on azure, websites are in node.js on port 300 and django on port 8000 and i have to provide port in URL for example to see front-end part i have to go to MYWEBSITE.southeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:3000 and for back-end MYWEBSITE.southeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8000. How do i change that? So the port is not needed for it to work.

Comment: @NiewaszBiznes I don't think it's possible if you use the Azure VM only. Because VM has many ports and you cannot route the request to the right port if you do not append the port behind. If you use the Web App, then you do not need to append the port behind the URL.

Comment: yea but i think there has to be some way to deal with it right? Beacuse i don't think noone uses VM on azure or somewhere else and didn't think of solution for it right?

Comment: @NiewaszBiznes Only use VM cannot solve it. You need to use other services to cooperate with the VM.

Comment: ok i understand, can you recommend something for it that worked for you?

Comment: @NiewaszBiznes You can try to use the Azure application gateway. And if the answer solves the issue for you, please accept it.